# JQuery UI Datepicker altfield not being populated

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am new to Javascript/client-side programming but as I understand from all the posts i have read about JQuery UI's datepicker, the altfield for datepicker will be populated with the same value as the datepicker without the need to create a function to populate it on change or select. However, I have set my altfield for the 2 datepickers I have but they do not get populated or I am missing some configuration. Code below...

dates.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Datepicker Popups calender to Choose date.
$(function() {
$("#datepicker1").datepicker({
altField : "dbBegDate",
altFormat : "yy-mm-dd" }
);
$("#datepicker1").datepicker("setDate", "-1d");
$("#datepicker2").datepicker({
altField : "dbEndDate",
altFormat : "yy-mm-dd" }
);
$("#datepicker2").datepicker("setDate", "0d");
});
```

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="us">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>BES Bad Bucket Report Date Selection</title>
    <link href="./css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link href="./css/mydatepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>...
    <body>
       <div class="container">
       <h2>Bad Bucket Report Dates Selector</h2>
       <div class="main">
       <form action="index.jsp" method="post">
       <label>Beginning Date :</label>
       <input type="text" name="beg_date" id="datepicker1"/>
       <!-- <input type="hidden" id="dbBegDate" name="dbBegDate"/>-->
       <input type="text" id="dbBegDate" name="dbBegDate"/>

      <label>Ending Date :</label>
      <input type="text" name="end_date" id="datepicker2"/>
      <input type="hidden" id="dbEndDate" name="dbEndDate"/>

      <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
 </div>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

When I try to get the dates from altfields in index.jsp, it is a null value. The datepicker values return the valid selected date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As JQuery UI API defined:

> **altField**: **Type**: Selector or jQuery or Element; **Default** Value: ""

So you can use '#' to match element id like `altField : "#dbBegDate"`.

After fixed this issue then below codes work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Datepicker Popups calender to Choose date.

  $("#datepicker1").datepicker({
    altField : "#dbBegDate",
    altFormat : "yy-mm-dd" 
  });
  $("#datepicker1").datepicker("setDate", "-1d");
  $("#datepicker2").datepicker({
    altField : "#dbEndDate",
    altFormat : "yy-mm-dd" 
  });
  $("#datepicker2").datepicker("setDate", "0d");
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="container">
   <!-- <h2>Bad Bucket Report Dates Selector</h2>-->
   <div class="main">
     <form action="index.jsp" method="post">
     <label>Beginning Date :</label>
     <input type="text" name="beg_date" id="datepicker1"/>
     <!-- <input type="hidden" id="dbBegDate" name="dbBegDate"/>-->
     <input type="text" id="dbBegDate" name="dbBegDate"/>
    <br/>
    <label>Ending Date :</label>
    <input type="text" name="end_date" id="datepicker2"/>
    <input type="text" id="dbEndDate" name="dbEndDate"/>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You da man! Thanks for the assist. I figured it had to be something simple due to my lack of Javascript or HTML knowledge. Thank you.